# How to insert emoticons in editable div codeigniter php

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I've converted text to emoticons using preg_replace like this,

```
 public function get_smiles() 
 {
 $text = preg_replace("/(^|[ ])\:\)/", "&#x1F60A;", "<img src='images/smileys/angry.gif'/>");
 return $text;
 }
```

And in codeigniter view,

```
  <?php $smiles = $this->libarary1->get_smiles(); ?>
  <?php foreach($smiles as $k=>$v) : ?>
    <button type="button" class="make-editable" onclick="add_smile(<?php $k ?>)"><?php echo $v ?></button>
    <?php echo $k; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The conversion of text to emoticon works fine.Now I want to display the emoticon in my editable div through onclick function.

```
function add_smile($t) {
    console.log($t);
    $("#inputbox")
   .attr('contenteditable', 'true')
   .html("$t");
   }
```

In the function converted emoticon prints **undefined** in my editable div.So how should I pass the emoticon to javascript function and get it into my edtable div?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot an **echo** in your code (*< ?php $k ?>*):

```
<button type="button" class="make-editable" onclick="add_smile('<?php echo $k ?>')"><?php echo $v ?></button>
```

Comment: when I use echo ,gives an error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`  in that line  `<button type="button" class="make-editable" onclick="add_smile(<img src='images/smileys/angry.gif'/>)">&#x1F60A;</button>`

Comment: Like this right?`<button type="button" class="make-editable" onclick="add_smile('/<?php echo $k ?>/')"><?php echo $v ?></button>
`

Comment: Thanks for your code but this `<button type="button" class="make-editable" onclick="add_smile('<?php echo $k ?>')"><?php echo $v ?></button>
` also gives error

Answer (score 0):

You could carefully escape each of the quotes because it is deeply nested, so it will not break each other :

```
public function get_smiles() {
    $text = preg_replace("/(^|[ ])\:\)/", "&#x1F60A;", '\'\"<img src=\\\'images/smileys/angry.gif\\\'/>\"\'');
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: I've done conversion from string to image through preg_relace,when I retrn it to my codeigniter,It works fine.But how 'ld pass it through javascript function to place in my input field?

Comment: I've updated the code, it missing closing double-quotes. You could pass the `$text` like that, so the button element will have escaped version of it to be used on `add_smile()` function, hope it helps..